# Table Pagination with Semantic UI React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a [`<Table>`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/) component from `semantic-ui-react` that I use to render fetched data from a mocked api call. I could potentially have `X` amount of rows, so I'm looking into adding pagination. I have found some solutions but they look entirely too bulky.

Can anyone give some suggestions on how to approach handling simple pagination? Let's say I only want to render 5 rows of data on every page. How can I achieve this?

I have a [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-thunder-9ilbp).

```
class PaginationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { tableData: [], activePage: 1 };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getData();
  }

  getData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/slotInfo");
    console.log(data);
    const tableData = data.data.slotInfo;
    this.setState({ tableData: tableData });
  };

  //change handlers for pagination

  handlePageClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activePage: name });

  render() {
    const { tableData, activePage } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Table Pagination w/ SUI-React Component</h1>
        <Table style={{ marginTop: "5em" }} inverted celled>
          <Table.Header fullWidth>
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Slot Id</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>deviceId</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Initialized</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Label</Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Header>

          <Table.Body>
            {Object.values(tableData).map(
              ({ slotId, deviceId, initialized, label }) => {
                return (
                  <Table.Row>
                    <Table.Cell>{slotId}</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell>{deviceId}</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell>{initialized}</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell>{label}</Table.Cell>
                  </Table.Row>
                );
              }
            )}
          </Table.Body>

          <Table.Footer>
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell colSpan="4">
                <Menu floated="right" pagination>
                  <Menu.Item as="a" icon>
                    <Icon name="chevron left" />
                  </Menu.Item>
                  <Menu.Item
                    name="1"
                    active={activePage === "1"}
                    onClick={this.handlePageClick}
                  />
                  <Menu.Item
                    name="2"
                    active={activePage === "2"}
                    onClick={this.handlePageClick}
                  />
                  <Menu.Item
                    name="3"
                    active={activePage === "3"}
                    onClick={this.handlePageClick}
                  />
                  <Menu.Item
                    name="4"
                    active={activePage === "4"}
                    onClick={this.handlePageClick}
                  />
                  <Menu.Item as="a" icon>
                    <Icon name="chevron right" />
                  </Menu.Item>
                </Menu>
              </Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Footer>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the pagination component from Semantic UI?
https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/pagination/

Basically you only need to provide the props `totalPages`, `activePage`/`defaultActivePage` and `onPageChange` which you will use for your page change function.

Comment: I understand that, but how would I handle number of rows rendered per page?

Comment: There are two ways: Usually your API endpoint should be capable of doing pagination, meaning it provides pages/totalItems and a limit attribute with whom you can request e.g. the first 10 items (page 1), the second 10 items (page 2). Often it looks like: "endpoint?offset=1&limit=10".

If your endpoint only provides all data at once you need to implement that logic in the frontend. (But it is not that cool way.) In that case I probably would save the results in a store and access them in the same logic as backend would provide in best case (offset & limit).